# Как написать сервер и api к нему? Как сделать это правильнее? .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Пишу мобильное приложение по типу магазина на MAUI. Но не могу понять, как лучше всего сделать сервер и получать из него данные. Где можно почитать или посмотреть, как это делается. На сайте metaint в гайдах используется [ASP.NET Core Web Application](https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/10.4.php). Актуален он ли сейчас или есть аналоги лучше.

Comment: Вам нужен ASP.NET Web API. Использовать API можно из приложения любого типа. / Однако, API можно реализовать по-разному: REST, GraphQL и др. Выбирайте то, с чем лучше знакомы или что хотите изучить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET актуален, вы можете использовать его в .NET 6, возможно, что гайды по Core версии будут не очень актуальны в том плане, что там используется класс Startup, который сейчас объединен с Program. API вы сможете создать в несколько кликов через APIController и добавить\убрать необходимое.
Консольное у вас приложение, MAUI или Avalonia, это никак не влияет на серверную часть. Про Rest и прочее вам правильно написали. Ваша задача будет только в том, чтобы из MAUI делать запросы в нужном формате и получать ответ от сервера.